# A picture puzzle - What am I?

Tags: riddle, visual

Here's my first picture-puzzle riddle:

[image: corn]

[image: a green tree]

[image: a wedding garter]

[image: head of the statue of liberty]

[image: a basketball]

[image: The white king chess piece]

**What am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're a

> snake

because there are:

> corn snakes
>  (green) tree snakes
>  garter snakes
>  copperheads (ha, punny!)
>  ball pythons
>  king snakes

Comment: Spot on Will.  Well done.

Comment: So basically *Kill Bill 3*.